# Suggestion with MVC2 DI and migrating a legacy system

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-mvc-2, structuremap, .net-standard

I have an old legacy system (more than 10 years) made in MVC 2 with structuremap(2.6.1.0) as DI. We have begun migrating the back with nHibernate (also 10 years old) to entity framework core in a standard library.

But this doesn't work so easy, this old structure map wants to map everything in standard library also and that wont work. I would need to make it ignore the standard library, any suggestion how I should do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cant be done. Structuremap doesn't support standard 2.0..
Went back to EF6 and will do the migration to EF core once the MVC is upgraded to core(and stucturemap is not needed in mvc2 anymore)